# ERROR Jboss after edit of standalone.xml

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-eap-6

Hello i was working on implementing HTTPS to a part of an application, not the whole pages.

**I have created another subsystem in my XML file:**

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.5" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
         <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" enable-lookups="false" secure="true">
            <ssl name="kikou-ssl" key-alias="kikou" password="orange" certificate-key-file="../standalone/configuration/kikou.keystore" protocol="TLSv1" verify-client="false"/>
        </connector>
   </subsystem>
```

I thought if i have tow subsystems one will be used to HTTPS and the other to HTTP.

I have also edited the file **web.xml** in my eclipse with :

```
 <security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>optional</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/sitesApi2/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

But when i started the server i got this **ERROR**, Can you explain to me please, what's wrong !

```
016-03-25 09:28:21,606 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015956: Exception interceptée au démarrage: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: N'a pas pu analyser la configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:141) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:308) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:188) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[273,4]
Message: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:web:1.5}subsystem'
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:108) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.handleAny(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.parseServerProfile(StandaloneXml.java:1028) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readServerElement_1_4(StandaloneXml.java:449) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:136) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:103) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:133) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
```

Thank you for your suggestions ! 
********************Edition***********Extensions*************

```
    <extensions>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jsf"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.threads"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.web"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
</extensions>
```

Comment: Any thing ?, even an idea, i just want to have a lead to use. thank you

Comment: What version of JBoss? Be specific. Also `Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:web:1.5}subsystem'` means that the element is not in the right place, or the version of the element is not supported.

Comment: @TT hello i have Jboss EAP6.1, and as i said i wanted to have https but not for all the app so i added a new subsystem. with https and left the other one with http, what do you think?

Comment: You may not want to, but I think you should include more of the `standalone.xml` (perferably the whole file - blank out any sensitive info). As it is now, it is hard to say if you misplaced the element. Also to see what namespace versions you use in other elements. So I suggest instead of the excerpt at the top of your question, you `edit` your question (`edit` link is below the question), paste the standalone.xml contents and format it using the `{}` button.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that it can't parse `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.5"...`. JBoss EAP 6.1 uses version 1.4 of the schema for the web subsystem. Try changing the `1.5` to `1.4`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the extension element in your subsystem ?

```
<extension module="org.jboss.as.web" />
```

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Subsystem+configuration

The web subsystem configuration basically consists of three parts: The JSP Configuration, connectors and virtual servers. Advanced topics like load balancing and failover are covered on the "High Availability Guide". The default configuration does is suitable for most use cases and provides reasonable performance settings.

Required extension:

```
<extension module="org.jboss.as.web" />
```

Basic subsystem configuration example:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.0" default-virtual-server="default-host">
    <connector name="http" scheme="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" socket-binding="http"/>
    <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
       <alias name="localhost" />
       <alias name="example.com" />
    </virtual-server>
 </subsystem>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and yes i did add the extension !  i'll edit my question to see what extension did i add.

Comment: can you post your complete standalone.xml , it will be helpful